# Deleting files older than a certain date inside multiple directories

Tags: logging, cron

I want to delete files that are older than 2 days in multiple directories.
[image: file tree]

This is the file tree. I want to delete every file that is older than 2 days that are inside the directories named as integers.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one using:

```
forfiles /p "C:\backup\logs" /s /m *.* /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Type this on notepad use your path and days.
Save this file as `.bat` and run.

Hope it works